# Insufficient Transport Layer Protection iOS

Tags: react-native, security, ssl

We are developing an application in react-native. Our security team has raised a vulnerability in iOS binary. The description of the vulnerability is given below.

> The application has references to potentially risky symbols that
> modify the default SSL certificate validation.
>
> The behavior of iOS's TLS/SSL libraries' certificate validation is
> intended to be secure by default (CFNetwork, Foundation, etc). These
> libraries validate a number of security items such as certificate
> expiration dates and known root certificates.
>
> This application was found to reference symbols that can be used to
> modify the default validation behavior for TLS/SSL certificates. When
> the default validation is modified the potential exists to
> inadvertently weaken the security of the TLS/SSL protocol and thereby
> making the traffic more susceptible to interception or modification by
> attackers. The binary contains references to methods that may result
> in vulnerable SSL connections:
>
> _kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain

We have not implemented SSL pinning in the app. We are not sure how to fix this issue and the security team has not been able to provide any additional information. They use some automated tool which identified the issue and provides only following recommendation which we could not find very helpful in remediating the vulnerability.

> Review the application's and third party library's code for the use of
> these symbols to ensure they are not being used to weaken the TLS/SSL
> security. Some of the symbols detected may be deprecated or involve
> non-public APIs so a review of the code is encouraged for compliance
> with Apple's App Store policies.
>
> Please note that the presence of these symbols does not indicate
> insecure usage as they may be used to check for or explicitly set
> default values. These symbols may also be found in code designed to
> perform non-standard certificate validation, such as custom SSL
> pinning implementations.

Any help provided by the community in identifying and fixing this issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: Err, 'Review the application's and third party library's code'?

Comment: Precisely that's what the security team has provided as a recommendation. We have reviewed our code and haven't found any reference to such symbol. If it is injected by some library during compilation then we don't know which library is doing that. And that is the biggest challenge.